# Can't login to admin panel in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, login, admin-login, admin-user

I get the error 'You did not sign in correctly or your account is temporarily disabled'.

I've already run:

```
php bin/magento admin:user:unlock vixent
```

or modified the password in database:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password = CONCAT(SHA2('my_pass', 256), ':xxxxx') WHERE username = 'vixent';
```

The problem occurred when Magento asked me to change the password after login but when I clicked on 'Save' button, I got some errors and magento logs out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea what the problem might be, but you can still get access by creating another admin account:

> php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user="USERNAME_HERE" --admin-password="YOUR PASSWORD HERE" --admin-email="your-email-here@email.com" --admin-firstname="FIRST NAME HERE" --admin-lastname="LAST NAME HERE"

After this you should use the new account to login and try to see what's wrong with your old account.

Comment: Thanks, I added a new account and I deleted the old account...

Answer (score 1):

You just create new USER using following command and login with new user and reset your old user password.

> php bin/magento admin:user:create --admin-user='new-user' --admin-password='admin123' --admin-email='admin@admin.com' --admin-firstname='Admin' --admin-lastname='Admin'

Hope it'll helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (I think this happens because email server is not set in my vm), I used this update statement to fix user password

```
UPDATE admin_user SET `password` = CONCAT(SHA2('xxxxxxxxadmin123', 256), ':xxxxxxxx:1') WHERE `username` = 'admin';
```

user is

> admin

new password is

> admin123

The xxxxxxxx character sequence is a cryptographic salt. It can be anything you want, but make sure you use the same value in both parts of the SQL statement.

I hope this helps, happy coding!